# Prove the existence of a greatest lower bound of $X$ if $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a non-empty set that is bounded below

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Attempt:

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ be the set of all lower bounds of $X$. Since $C$ is not empty and bounded above, every $x \in X$ is an upper bound of every element $c \in C$. Thus, there exists an $a$ such that $a = \sup C$ and $c \leq a \leq x$ for every element in $C$. Notice that, by the supremum property, $a \leq x$ for all $x \in X$, thus $a$ is a lower bound for $X$. In fact, for any other lower bound $p$ for $X$, we have $p \in C$ and $p \leq a$ since $a = \sup C$. Thus $a = \inf X$.

Question: Is it true that in $\mathbb{R}$ for non-empty sets $X,C \in \mathbb{R}$ described as above where $C$ is the set of lower bounds of $X$, that the $\inf X = \sup C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the attempt, you can't conclude that $sup(C)\in X$ since for example if $X=\{x:x>2\}$ then $C=\{c:c\leq 2\}$ and $sup(C)=2\notin X$. You can however, conclude that $sup(C)\in C$, since the supremum should also be a lower bound.
To your question - yes:

- if inf(X) < sup(C) then there exists $x\in X, c\in C$ s.t. $0\leq x-inf(X)< 0.3(sup(C)-inf(X))$, and $0\leq sup(C)-c <  0.3(sup(C)-inf(X))$. This means that
  $inf(X) \leq x < c \leq sup(C)$, which obviously contradicts C being a set of lower bounds to X (c is larger that x).
- inf(X) > sup(C) then $c_0=inf(X)- 0.5(inf(X)-sup(C))$ is also a lower bound, to X (so $c_0\in C$), but $c_0 > sup(C)$ which is a contradiction.

Thus concludes inf(X)=sup(C).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. So I replaced $x_0$ with $a$ in my proof above which I think corrects the argument. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes it seems OK. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes; the infimum of a set is the greatest lower bound, and therefore would be the greatest element in the set of lower bounds, making it the supremum of the set of lower bounds immediately.